# How to connect Kafka connect Cassandra Sink connector with AWS Keyspaces?

Tags: apache-kafka, cassandra, apache-kafka-connect, datastax, amazon-keyspaces

I'm using Datastax' Cassandra Kafka connect Sink Connector to try and move some data from AWS MSK to AWS Keyspaces, Kafka connect is running within an EC2 instance.

I'm having trouble to connect Kafka connect to AWS Keyspaces, as I keep getting the following error:

```
"name":"test_connector_1","connector":{"state":"RUNNING","worker_id":"some_address:8083"},"tasks":[{"id":0,"state":"FAILED","worker_id":"some_address:8083","trace":"com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.AllNodesFailedException: Could not reach any contact point, make sure you've provided valid addresses (showing first 1 nodes, use getAllErrors() for more): Node(endPoint=cassandra.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/some_address:9142, hostId=null, hashCode=1e3c56f4)
```

My EC2 instance has IAM permissions `cassandra:Modify` and `cassandra:Select` on all resources for testing, and I also followed [this tutorial](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/keyspaces/latest/devguide/using_java_driver.html#using_java_driver.BeforeYouBegin) to ensure connection.
But I keep getting the same error. I am not entirely sure that I can use this connector to move data to AWS Keyspaces so I don't know if this is expected.

the connector config is the following:

```
curl -i -X POST -H "Content-Type:application/json" localhost:8083/connectors -d '{
"name":"test_connector_1",
"config":{
  "contactPoints":"cassandra.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
  "loadBalancing.localDc":"us-east-1",
  "port":"9142",
  "consistencyLevel":"QUORUM",
  "connector.class":"com.datastax.oss.kafka.sink.CassandraSinkConnector",
  "tasks.max":"1",
  "topics":"keyspaces_connector_test",
 "topic.keyspaces_connector_test.connector_keyspace.key_value_test.mapping":"client_id=key, message=value",
  "ssl.truststore.path":"/some/path/cassandra_truststore.jks",
  "ssl.truststore.password":"some password"
  }
}'
```

Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I recommend trying cqlsh from that EC2 server to verify connection

Comment: I can connect with cqlsh using a vpc endpoint, but when I provide that endpoint to the connector it says `make sure you've provided valid addresses` with a Failed state

Comment: Do the examples in the repos work? https://github.com/DataStax-Examples/kafka-connector-sink-json/blob/master/README.md Maybe try contacting Datastax support directly?